# PostgresSql - Filtering data between dates which in format like Mon Jun 20 2022 10:04:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter, filtering

PostgresSql - Filtering data between dates which in format like Mon Jun 20 2022 10:04:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time). I want to filter data between 2 dates

i.stack.imgur.com/Hu91J.jpg

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: What datatype is the column you want to filter on?

Comment: That should be `GMT-05:30`.

Comment: Those are not dates.